# Uncaught TypeError: u(...).getServerUrl is not a function in HTML Web Resource

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm

I'm guessing this code would work fine on a form. I always seem to have problems with `Xrm.Page.Context` and methods like `getServerUrl` when I am working on javascript within an HTML web resource.

Here is the function I am trying to run:

```js
function getAttributeOptions(entityLogicalName, attributeLogicalName, dictionaryObject, onComplete) {
    ///<summary>
    /// <para>Retrieves the picklist attribute options and appends them to a dictionary object.</para>
    /// <para>It then executes the function assigned to the onComplete parameter.</para>
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="entityLogicalName" type="String">
    /// The logical name of the entity
    ///</param>
    ///<param name="attributeLogicalName" type="String">
    /// The logical name of the Picklist attribute
    ///</param>
    ///<param name="dictionaryObject" type="Object">
    /// An empty object that will become a dictionary for the option values.
    ///</param>
    ///<param name="onComplete" type="Function">
    /// A function to perform when the options are assigned to the dictionaryObject;
    ///</param>
    if (!(typeof entityLogicalName == "string")) {
        throw new Error("getAttributeOptions entityLogicalName parameter is required and must be a string.");
    }
    if (!(typeof attributeLogicalName == "string")) {
        throw new Error("getAttributeOptions attributeLogicalName parameter  is required and  must be a string.");
    }
    if (!(typeof dictionaryObject == "object")) {
        throw new Error("getAttributeOptions dictionaryObject parameter is required and must be an object.");
    }
    if (!(typeof onComplete == "function")) {
        throw new Error("getAttributeOptions onComplete parameter is required and must be a function.");
    }

    var passThroughObject = {};
    passThroughObject.eln = entityLogicalName;
    passThroughObject.aln = attributeLogicalName;
    passThroughObject.dObj = dictionaryObject;
    passThroughObject.oc = onComplete;

    if ((typeof SDK == "undefined") || (typeof SDK.Metadata == "undefined") || (typeof SDK.Metadata.Query == "undefined")) {
        throw new Error("getAttributeOptions function requires the SDK.Metadata.Query.min.js library and it is not present.");
    }

    var mdq = SDK.Metadata.Query;
    var semp = mdq.SearchableEntityMetadataProperties;
    var samp = mdq.SearchableAttributeMetadataProperties;
    var srmp = mdq.SearchableRelationshipMetadataProperties
    var emp = mdq.EntityMetadataProperties;
    var amp = mdq.AttributeMetadataProperties;
    var rmp = mdq.RelationshipMetadataProperties;
    var ve = mdq.ValueEnums;

    //EntityFilter
    var ef = new mdq.MetadataFilterExpression(mdq.LogicalOperator.And);
    ef.addCondition(semp.LogicalName, mdq.MetadataConditionOperator.Equals, entityLogicalName);
    //Entity Properties
    var ep = new mdq.MetadataPropertiesExpression(false, [emp.Attributes]);

    //Attribute Filter
    var af = new mdq.MetadataFilterExpression(mdq.LogicalOperator.And);
    af.addCondition(samp.LogicalName, mdq.MetadataConditionOperator.Equals, attributeLogicalName);

    //Attribute Properties
    var ap = new mdq.MetadataPropertiesExpression(false, [amp.OptionSet, amp.AttributeType]);
    // AttributeQuery
    var aq = new mdq.AttributeQueryExpression(af, ap);
    // LabelQuery
    var lq = new mdq.LabelQueryExpression([1033]);
    //EntityQueryExpression
    var eqe = new mdq.EntityQueryExpression(ef, ep, aq, null, lq);
    //RetrieveMetadataChangesRequest
    var rmcr = new mdq.RetrieveMetadataChangesRequest(eqe, null, mdq.DeletedMetadataFilters.Default);

    mdq.RetrieveMetadataChanges(
        rmcr,
        function(rmcResponse, pto) {
            var attributeType = "unknown";
            if (typeof rmcResponse.EntityMetadata[0] == "undefined" || rmcResponse.EntityMetadata[0] == null) {
                throw new Error("No entity metadata found for " + pto.eln);
            }
            if (typeof rmcResponse.EntityMetadata[0].Attributes[0] == "undefined" || rmcResponse.EntityMetadata[0].Attributes[0] == null) {
                throw new Error("No attribute metadata found for " + pto.eln + "." + pto.aln);
            }
            if (typeof rmcResponse.EntityMetadata[0].Attributes[0].OptionSet == "undefined" || rmcResponse.EntityMetadata[0].Attributes[0].OptionSet == null) {
                throw new Error(pto.eln + "." + pto.aln + " does not have an OptionSet property.");
            }
            attributeType = rmcResponse.EntityMetadata[0].Attributes[0].AttributeType;
            if (attributeType != "Boolean") {
                if (typeof rmcResponse.EntityMetadata[0].Attributes[0].OptionSet.Options == "undefined" || rmcResponse.EntityMetadata[0].Attributes[0].OptionSet.Options == null) {
                    throw new Error(pto.eln + "." + pto.aln + "OptionSet does not have an Options property");
                }
                if (typeof rmcResponse.EntityMetadata[0].Attributes[0].OptionSet.Options[0] == "undefined" || rmcResponse.EntityMetadata[0].Attributes[0].OptionSet.Options[0] == null) {
                    throw new Error(pto.eln + "." + pto.aln + "OptionSet.Options does not have any options");
                }
            }


            pto.dObj[pto.eln] = pto.dObj[pto.eln] || {};
            pto.dObj[pto.eln].attributes = pto.dObj[pto.eln].attributes || {};
            pto.dObj[pto.eln].attributes[pto.aln] = pto.dObj[pto.eln].attributes[pto.aln] || {};
            pto.dObj[pto.eln].attributes[pto.aln].options = pto.dObj[pto.eln].attributes[pto.aln].options || {};
            if (attributeType != "Boolean") {
                for (var i in rmcResponse.EntityMetadata[0].Attributes[0].OptionSet.Options) {
                    var option = rmcResponse.EntityMetadata[0].Attributes[0].OptionSet.Options[i];
                    pto.dObj[pto.eln].attributes[pto.aln].options[option.Value] = option.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label;
                }
            } else {
                pto.dObj[pto.eln].attributes[pto.aln].options[0] = rmcResponse.EntityMetadata[0].Attributes[0].OptionSet.FalseOption.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label;
                pto.dObj[pto.eln].attributes[pto.aln].options[1] = rmcResponse.EntityMetadata[0].Attributes[0].OptionSet.TrueOption.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label;
            }

            pto.oc(pto.eln, pto.aln);
        },
        function(error) {
            writeMessage(error.message);
        },
        passThroughObject);

}

// MetaDataDictionary
var mdd = {};

function testResults(entityLogicalName, attributeLogicalName) {
    alert("Options for " + entityLogicalName + "." + attributeLogicalName + " cached.");
}
getAttributeOptions("contact", "statecode", mdd, testResults);

for (option in mdd.contact.attributes.statecode.options) {
    var value = option;
    var label = mdd.contact.attributes.statecode.options[option];
    alert(label);
}
```

Here is the problematic part of the library that I am using:

```js
function u() {
            var n = "Context is not available.";
            return typeof GetGlobalContext != "undefined" ? GetGlobalContext() : typeof Xrm != "undefined" ? Xrm.Page.context : new Error(n)
        }

        function h() {
            var n = u().getServerUrl();
            return n.match(/\/$/) && (n = n.substring(0, n.length - 1)), typeof u().getClientUrl != "undefined" && (n = u().getClientUrl()), n
        }
```

Here is my error:

[image]

I'd really like for `getServerUrl` and `getClientUrl` to be available to me. What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Verify the path & add this library in your HTML webresource to access CRM context.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"></script>
```

> When you need context information outside a form, include a reference to the ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx page in an HTML web resource.

[GetGlobalContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/gg328541.aspx#GetGlobalContext%20function)

Also `getServerUrl` is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7d0b052-abca-4f81-9b86-0b9dc5e62a66#BKMK_getclienturl), you have to use `getClientUrl` based on your CRM version.

Comment: That looks very promising. However, the library I was using was SDK.Metadata.Query.min.js. It turns out much of this library is depreciated but I had to read quite a few paragraphs here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919080(v=crm.6).aspx to realize that. I ended up using this complicated Web API request uri to get the data I wanted: http://clienturl/api/data/v8.2/EntityDefinitions(608861bc-50a4-4c5f-a02c-21fe1943e2cf)/Attributes/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.StateAttributeMetadata?$select=LogicalName&$expand=OptionSet,GlobalOptionSet I'll try to verify your answer one of these days soon.